# msvcp120.dll and msvcr120.dll are missing in redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I am using windows server 2012 R2. My application is dependent on msvcp120.dll and msvcr120.dll. After searaching I got to know that these files are present in redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013. I installed it, but these files are still missing in system32 folder.

So can any one tell me which package will install these dlls. I don't want to copy these dlls manually.

Comment: Are you mixing 32 and 64 bit here? I mean there is a 32 bit redistributable and a separate 64 bit redistributable. If you are building a 32 bit application you need to install the 32 bit version even though your OS is 64 bit.

Comment: This is covered on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235299.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

There are files that you, when developing a C++ application, should deploy with your application. You should find them somewhere inside

```
\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist
```

This is a problem that arises often if you want to make a quick test on another PC of an application you are developing without providing a true installer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I found dlls at the location that you mentioned. As these files are not copied in system32 folder, Would I need to add "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist" in path environment variable? So that my application can find it.

Comment: I would prefer to copy them in the folder of your app. system32 is a crowded place...